# Russia is huge and well militarised. Why did it end up asking Kazakhstan for troops?

Tags: russian-federation, military, ukraine

As [reported today](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/live-blog/russia-ukraine-live-updates-n1289976/ncrd1289985), Kazakhstan has denied a request by Russia for troops to join Russian forces in Ukraine.

Setting aside all discussion of why Kazakhstan answered as it did, why on earth was Russia asking?

Russia is huge, with a substantial military, Putin control and presumed preplanning for a long time. That would mean they'd know their strength and be ready with what they need. No country launches an attack only to ask others to lend them more troops just days later.  Especially a preplanned major attack.  I don't quite believe that strong resistance covers it.

Looking for less obvious possible reasons, the only one I can think of is that it hoped past allies would offer troops it didn't really need, that it could use to show how other countries supported it?

So why did Russia end up in a situation where bare days after invading, it went almost cap in hand, it sounds like, asking allies for further troops?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question appears to be very speculative. I can't imagine an answer which would not be based on wild guessing and unproven hypothesis at this point.

Answer (score 4):

I've not seen a Russian confirmation of the request, but if I am to hypothesize why such a request might be made is to show some kind of broad(er) coalition support for Moscow's actions. ([Something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_United_States_presidential_debates#%22You_forgot_Poland%22) that even US presidents were keen to emphasize occasionally.)

To wit, when Russian troops recently went *into* Kazakhstan, it was under [such auspices](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/01/07/kazakhstan-russia-troops-csto/):

> Russia’s intervention in Kazakhstan is unique compared with Moscow’s previous military operations in the former Soviet space, such as in Georgia in 2008 and Ukraine in 2014. One unique aspect is the involvement of the CSTO, which is a military alliance consisting of Russia and its strongest security allies in the post-Soviet space, including Armenia, Belarus, Kazakhstan, Kyrgyzstan, and Tajikistan. Unlike Russia’s operations in Georgia and Ukraine, the deployment of CSTO troops (the majority of which come from Russia but also with smaller contingents from CSTO members Armenia, Belarus, and Tajikistan) was explicitly requested by Kazakh President Kassym-Jomart Tokayev and did not come against the government. With the situation rapidly spinning out of control, Tokayev felt the need to get CSTO assistance in order to secure strategic sites and installations, including government buildings and airports in key cities such as Almaty, while Kazakh security forces could focus on handling the demonstrators directly. And indeed, the multinational nature of the intervention is significant, serving as the first joint deployment of CSTO forces in the 30-year history of the security bloc.

There's some further [analysis](https://warontherocks.com/2022/02/how-a-russian-led-alliance-keeps-a-lid-on-central-asia/) of the CSTO deployment numbers in Kazakhstan:

> According to conservative estimates, CSTO sent about 2500 troops to Kazakhstan. About 100 came from Armenia, 200 from Belarus, 150 from Kyrgyzstan, and 200 from Tajikistan. While the exact number of Russian troops is not publicly available, the above estimates suggest that Moscow sent about 1850 troops, constituting almost 75 percent of the deployed force. Overall, the CSTO is an overwhelmingly Russian project from the political, financial, and military points of view.

As you can see Russia sent most of the troops. I would not expect they'd need support from Kazakhstan, especially so soon afher that country's internal troubles (Jan 2022), except as some kind of token support.